# run a piece of code after 30 min after the entry in db, in laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

I am working on Laravel as a back-end for mobile app.

As the app make the entry in db, then after 30 minutes I have to send push notification to the app indicating that you have used the app for 30 minutes.

Does **queue** and **cron** will solve my problem? Or is there any other way to do this? I am new to Laravel. please give me some suggestions.

Comment: you can use `Task Scheduling` in `Laravel`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: It would probably be worth look at events and listeners alongside scheduling and commands with the Laravel docs

Comment: @Saman the task scheduler for every minute, will make my website slow?

Answer (score 2):

The queue is enough for this task. You should use [delayed dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#delayed-dispatching). When users use an api endpoint or create some entity you dispatch delaying 30 minutes. Something like this:

```
SendNotification::dispatch($podcast)->delay(now()->addMinutes(30));
```